# Iterating through the Rails lib folder to find children

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code is meant to determine which subclass of itself to execute. It cycles through everything in the ObjectSpace to find subclasses and then execute the correct one from there. In rails, this does not work, because classes in the library folder are not in the ObjectSpace. What is a way to search through a specific folder for subclasses?

```
def execute
  ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select do |klass|
    if (klass < self.class)
      klass.designations.each do |designation|
        if (designation.downcase.capitalize == @action.downcase.capitalize)
          command = klass.new(@sumo_params)
          command.execute
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

OR -- Is there a superior solution to this problem that you would recommend?

Comment: can you just require every file in lib to get them loaded? then, your classes will be in memory and you can go about this craziness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the easy way out for now (iterating through an array of string values):

```
def execute
  @descendants.each do |descendant|
    klass = descendant.downcase.capitalize.constantize
    if (klass < self.class)
      klass.designations.each do |designation|
        if (designation.downcase.capitalize == @action.downcase.capitalize)
          command = klass.new(@sumo_params)
          command.execute
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say use a module for this. So, this would make you code something like the following:

lib/base_methods.rb

```
module BaseMethods

  def self.included(base)
    @@classes_including ||= []
    @@classes_including << base
  end

  def do_whatever
    @@classes_including.each do |class|
      #....
    end
  end

end
```

lib/class_1.rb

```
class Class1
  include BaseMethods
end
```